# why the iterator is blocking forever when the

Tags: python, python-asyncio, producer-consumer

I have a piece of code that consists of both a consumer and a producer.

The consumer is basically iterate over a shared queue, however, an interesting thing is that when the consuming speed is faster than that of producing like below, the code below will be blocked at the iterator and the while loop in push_queue is also blocked.

```
class Ntest(object):
    def __init__(self, q):
        self.queue = q

    async def push_queue(self) -> None:
        counter = 0
        while True:
            self.queue.put(str(counter))
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
            counter = counter + 1

    async def print_queue(self) -> None:
        for elem in iter(self.queue.get, None):
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print(elem)
```

```
async def main():
    q = queue.Queue()
    ntest = Ntest(q)
    await asyncio.gather(ntest.push_queue(), ntest.print_queue())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Could someone can explain to me why it is blocked in this way given I am expecting push_queue will keep pushing item into queue and print_queue will only be blocked when the queue is empty?

Answer (score 2):

You are using synchronous queue here `q = queue.Queue()` which leads to blocking.
Please use **asyncio.Queue** https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-queue.html to have it working asynchronously

Comment: I know it leads to blocking but shouldn't the iterator part got unblocked once there are elements inside the queue ?

Comment: Element never gets there because execution is linear and execution flow is never returned to scheduler.  So, when we execute *self.queue.get* and queue is empty we get stuck forever there and we never executing *push_queue* because we block. 
In simple words, imagine people line in front of a checkout. If person(async) is busy and can't checkout in that moment, it lets the next person to go to the checkout. If person(sync) is busy, it holds whole line and nobody gets to the checkout.